# How to MD5 an input value based on function calculation

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am getting the result of signgen() as a value of input field with id="sign" onload. Is there any easy way to get this value as md5?
I think I've seen all of the stackoverflow answers but they all seem to be too complicated for this easy task. 
Is there a way to us php md5() function?
Thanks a lot for any help on that.

```
<html>  
<body onload="signgen()">
<form action="url" method="post" class="form">
<input type="text" name="session_id" id="session_id" value="<?php 
echo uniqid();?>" /> <br>
<input type="text" name="sign" id="sign"/> <br>
<input name="submit" value="wyślij" type="submit" /> <br>
</form>

<script>
function signgen(){
var sessionid = document.getElementById('session_id');
var mix = sessionid.value + "|abcde";
document.getElementById('sign').value = mix;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you send the value to a PHP script you can use `md5($_POST['session_id'])` there.

Comment: Don't perform client-side hashing of credentials without good reason. HTTPS + server side hashing (+salting) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. They put me on the right tracks.
What I finally did is after posting a form with action to another php file I used the data from the form via $_POST added salt (ie. "|abcde") then used the md5 function to create the hash.